# Can I return 2 times in a def function?

Tags: python, api

I have a problem with my code.I'm working with API now, and when I call it, it will show me some result. And I want to show a loading text like this : "300: Calculating" to know that my code is processing , untill the result show out , the "300: Calculating " text will disappear. And my code is in a def function.
My codeis roughly as below :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def Measurementwarning_response():

 i = 0
while i < 3:
    if  i == 1:
        message_code = "300: Calculating"
        predict_response1 = {
            "message_code": message_code,
        }
        predict_response = predict_response1
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(predict_response))
    

    if i == 2:
        message_code = "200. Sucessfully : Hello world"
        predict_response2 = {
            'message_code': message_code,

        }
        predict_response = predict_response2
        time.sleep(2)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(predict_response))
    i = i +1
```

I hope that after I call this API (Measurementwarning_response). The loading text "300: Calculating" will show out like this :
[This loading text "300: Calculating" will exisit whithin 2 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyIRF.png)

End then, after 2 seconds, the result "200. Sucessfully : Hello world" will show out. And "300: Calculating" text will disappear like this [This is the result will show out after 2 seconds and the "300: Calculating" text will disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn1Lg.png)

I have been tried to make a while loop and  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(predict_response)) 2 times. But it seems to be that I can not return 2 times in a function.I have been tried many times but I still can not do it. I hope you guys will take a look and comment in below to let me know what should I do with my code. Thank you guys so much

Comment: We can not write return 2 times in a def for API. Hint to do this: create 2 defs, add ajax in front end. Call 1st API, show loader. Once we get output of 1st API, call 2nd API

Comment: Or look into sockets, since a socket can "push" data to the client, your function can "push" a new value when the function is finished.

Comment: the problem is not returning two times from a function (generator functions can kind of do that) but that you can only return one response to an HTTP request

Comment: The way this would normally work is you first return a "please wait" page, then the frontend will 'poll' the backend (repeatedly make a request every x seconds) to check the status of the slow calculation, then when the calculation is complete and returns a result the frontend can display the success page.  An alternative to polling is Web Sockets where backend can 'push' the result when it is ready.

Answer (score 1):

return statement ends the function. so you cannot return twice. You can use yield and generator function in python as an alternative.
The yield statement suspends a function’s execution and sends a value back to the caller, but retains enough state to enable the function to resume where it left off. When the function resumes, it continues execution immediately after the last yield run. This allows its code to produce a series of values over time, rather than computing them at once and sending them back like a list.

```
def simpleGeneratorFun():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
 
 
# Driver code to check above generator function
for value in simpleGeneratorFun():
    print(value)
```

Output:
1
2
3

Comment: Just like my code above. I want to return 2 times . Fisrt to show "300:Calculating " on the client sceen, and then after 2 seconds, client's screen will show "200. Sucessfully : Hello world". I tried your code but it's can not return 2 result...

Comment: We cannot find what's wrong with the code that you tried, if you have not shared the code you have tried.

Comment: I post my code in the comment below . Because I dont knows how to post code inside your answer

Comment: You have not passed the argument to your function, please pass that argument and then check for the result.

Comment: Because my code is pretty long, so I did not post the middle part here. I had passed the argument when I run my code. When my client call my API, I want their screen will show the "predict_response1" in advanced , after 2 seconds show the "predict_response2". But I was only able to show 1 of them. Can not show both 2 Responses.